# setTimeout, fade out and go to url

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I am trying to create a function that after some time spending on a specific page, without any action of user, it will redirect him into another page, but with a fade out effect. Everything works good, except that the current page doesn't fade out, just simply goes to the new page. here is my code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('body').fadeOut('slow');
window.location.href = "index.html";
}, 6000);
```

Comment: [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete) takes an optional callback function: put the `href` setting in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fadeOut` method accepts another argument which is a `callback` function that's executed when the animation is complete, so, you can pass, alongside of the duration argument, a function that contains the redirection statement:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
  });
}, 6000);
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 2):

Put the location change in a callback to be run after the `fadeOut` completes.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    });
}, 6000);
```

This might make your `setTimeout` redundant. You probably just want:

```
$('body').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use *fadeout()* in document or html section:

```
$(document).fadeOut();
```

or

```
$("html").fadeOut();
```

I hope this helps.